# Is there any way to see what browser features are available for Chrome on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome

On caniuse it lists categories for Chrome and Chrome for Android. Ex: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overflow-anchor

Does that mean Chrome for iOS would be included under Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The only web render engine allowed on iOS is the iOS framework WKWebView. If the HTML5 feature isn't supported in the iOS Safari, it is unlikely that it is supported feature for third-party apps.

All other browsers you see in the iTunes store skin WKWebView adding features such as bookmark syncing, login fill-in, etc.